# Why java cant infer right type with Self bound generic type in subclasses

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, self-reference

Assume I have this code:

```
 class A<THIS extends A> {
        public THIS self() {
            return (THIS) this;
        }
    }

 class B extends A<B> { }

 A a = new A<>().self().self().self();  // OK
 B b = new B().self().self().self().self().self().self(); // OK
```

And it compiles fine.
But when I add one more inheritance level it does not work.

```
    class A<THIS extends A> {
        public THIS self() {
            return (THIS) this;
        }
    }
    class B<THIS extends B> extends A<B> { }
    class C extends B<C> { }

  A<A> self2 = new A<A>().self().self().self();  // OK
  B<B> self = new B<B>().self().self().self().self(); // error -> A
  C self1 = new C().self().self();  // error -> A
```

I tried different generic types but nothing helps.

What must I do to make this code compile?

Comment: You're using a raw type for `self`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: This approach is flawed. Corner case: `class D extends A<B> {}` compiles, but `new D().self().getClass()` will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is flawed.

It does not prevent a declaration such as

```
class D extends A<B> {
}
```

which will compile, but throw an exception at runtime, more specific:

```
new D().self().getClass() // => ClassCastException
```

---

To let classes provide functionality beyond their known superclass, you might try the *adapter* pattern.

It's base is usually an interface, like

```
interface Adaptable {
    T getAdapter(Class<? extends T> key);

    // for those who don't like to type long method names
    default T as(Class<? extends T> key) {
        return getAdapter(key);
    }
}
```

An implementation might look like

```
class A implements Adaptable {
    @Override
    public T getAdapter(Class<? extends T> key) {
        /*
         * To be less strict, one might also check for 'key.isInstance(this)',
         * but it's an implementation decision.
         */
        if(getClass() == key) {
            return key.cast(this);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, the *adapter* pattern allows to provide other objects, usually specialized views on the target, see the `FileSource` example below.

The major downside of this approach is that a client will always have to check on whether an adapter is available. However, if a client knew that an object *is* of the subclass it is looking for, it could simply cast it, so we don't really lose anything. The interface can also be extended using `java.util.Optional`, but the basic idea remains the same.

```
interface Adaptable {
    Optional<T> getAdapter(Class<? extends T> key);
}
```

---

For an example use case, let's say there is a `Source` class that models an available source for whatever process. As we know that source handling is often tricky and therefore hard to normalize into a single class or interface, we let the `Source` class implement `Adaptable`.

```
class Source implements Adaptable {
    @Override
    public Optional<T> getAdapter(Class<? extends T> key) {
        if(getClass() == key) {
            return Optional.of(key.cast(this));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Now there is a basic implementation, a `FileSource`, that is generally available as `java.io.File`.

```
class FileSource extends Source {
    private File pointer;

    public File asFile() {
        return pointer;
    }
}
```

A client can now check whether a source is available as file and perform some operation using the underlying `java.io.File`.

```
Source source;
...
source.getAdapter(FileSource.class).ifPresent(fileSource -> {
    File file = fileSource.asFile();
    // do your magic with 'file'
});
```

Even better, `FileSource` could simply provide an adapter for `File`. At this point, a client does not even need to care about the implementation subclass, but only on what s/he actually wants.

```
class FileSource extends Source {
    private File pointer;

    @Override
    public Optional<T> getAdapter(Class<? extends T> key) {
        if(File.class == key) {
            return Optional.of(key.cast(asFile()));
        }
        return super.getAdapter(key);
    }

    public File asFile() {
        return pointer;
    }
}
```

and

```
Source source;
...
source.getAdapter(File.class).ifPresent(file -> {
    // do your magic with file
});
```

Answer (score -1):

After few hours of suffering I find right way.

```
class A<THIS extends A<THIS>> {
    public THIS self() {
        return (THIS) this;
    }
}
class B<T extends B<T>> extends A<T> { }
class C<T extends C> extends B<C<T>> { }
A a = new A<>().self().self().self().self().self().self();     // OK
B b = new B<>().self().self().self().self().self().self();     // OK
C c = new C<>().self().self().self().self().self().self();    // OK
```

And yes it not safe like @Izruo points.